# How to link 2 versions of libc in to the same application?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, solaris, ld, libc

How can I force one particular module of my application to use an older version of libc?

I've got two .so files that I need to link into my application, but one of them will only work with an older version of libc and one will only work with a newer version.

I do have the source, but thus far tracking down the source of error has been unsuccessful.  I'm not stooping  that search, as that's certainly the correct fix.

As a temporary measure, is there anyway to force the linker to use the older libc for just that part of the application?

I'm OK with statically linking stuff and/or setting up symlinks.

**Update / Clarification:**

I'm trying to make this happen with no changes to the code base.  I'd like to figure out a way to tell the linker, that for this very specific .so file, any libc symbols should be made to point to the older copy of libc.

Even if/when I do find the real bug, this seems like an interesting enough challenge on it's own.

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can dynamically load an alternative library with dlopen then retrieve the address of symbols from it with dlsym. This allows you to get the address of functions and call their code instead of the default ones. See for example this [linker documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19504-01/802-6319/chapter3-14/index.html).

However, this would be at least complex to implement depending on the size of the code affected and worst, possibly doomed given the low-levelness of the standard C library and conflicts/mismatches that it might imply.

Understanding what's wrong with your code (or libc) would definitely be a better approach

**Update**:

There is a single name space for symbols so as far as I know, there is no way to tell  how to resolve symbols depending on the code origin. You definitely need to modify your code with the approach I suggest.

Alternatively, you might split your code in two programs linked with their respective libc and have them communicate through sockets, shared memory or whatever but that would also imply rewriting (and here re-architecturing) your code.

Comment: Interesting link, thank you.  Obviously the correct solution to find the bug, but that's not the point of the question. :) Can this be done at compiler flag level?  (I'll update the original post.)